# Can't deserialize object with custom Decoder of LocalDateTime in Scala circle json library

Tags: json, scala

I was trying to add custom deserializer to case class for `LocalDateTime` object however it pickups default deserializer from `circe-java8` module. If you remove this module, code will not compile (can't find deserializer for `LocalDateTime`)

sbt

```
"io.circe" %% "circe-core" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-optics" % circeVersion,
"io.circe" %% "circe-java8" % circeVersion,
```

And source code with custom `LocalDateTime` serializer/deserializer

```
case class A(
  date: LocalDateTime,
)

object A {
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  implicit val dateEncoder = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[LocalDateTime](_.format(formatter))
  implicit val dateDecoder = Decoder.decodeString.emap[LocalDateTime](str => {
    Either.catchNonFatal(LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter)).leftMap(_.getMessage)
  })
}
```

How to apply custom deserializer for `LocalDateTime` object specified in object `A` to `A` case class ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use semi-automatic derivation for `A`:

```
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

case class A(
  date: LocalDateTime,
)

object A {
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  implicit val dateEncoder = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[LocalDateTime](_.format(formatter))
  implicit val dateDecoder = Decoder.decodeString.emap[LocalDateTime](str => {
    Either.catchNonFatal(LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter)).leftMap(_.getMessage)
  })
  implicit val AEncoder = deriveEncoder[A]
  implicit val ADecoder = deriveDecoder[A]
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks.